# How to apply to a company where the technical recruiter wanted to fire me 12 years ago?

Tags: human-resources, cover-letter, france, apprentice, computer-science

I just graduated from my bachelor in computing and I’m looking for a 2 years apprenticeship for my Master degree. It’s been 2 months I’m searching and most colleges want a signed promise to hire in 2 weeks from now (deadline) in order for them to consider my application for their degrees.

Because of the little time left I’m thinking about sending a speculative application to a small insurance company where I did my secondary school’s internship (I was accepted there through a speculative application). On the first day there, I was asked to ask questions to peoples with desks located on the right side of the wall. Instead, I bothered peoples on the left side. The recruiter summoned me in his office for 2 hours prompting me to explain such behavior properly.
I made my case worst.
So in the afternoon, he dialed my secondary school in order to tell them he is firing me. They told him full rubbish about my mental health and he accepted to at least let me finish my internship there (I knew it through the recruiter telling me he never heard about such type of disorders and I was too much embarrassed to ask more details).
It was on the first day, but I didn’t use the remaining weeks to make the case better and they were several tasks I achieved differently from the way they were ordered (like using external scripts instead of complex Excel formulas for determining from the name of someone if she/he is male or female).

I left the company feeling I at least know a place that will refuse to hire me when I will be grown up. It happened 12 years ago… I never went back or talked to anyone there again… I never put that internship on my resume.

Since that time I had better work experiences and internships with sometimes getting the boss impressed with my work. But for someone knowing what happened there, the fact on my resume that I failed during several years at the exams of my bachelor degree would smell like I didn’t change.

**I checked the technical recruiter Linkedin profile’s and he still occupies the same position in the same company which means he is the guy to whom I need to send my apprenticeship application.**

On the other side I have a better episodic memory than most peoples, typically remembering details and peoples while other colleagues and bosses completely forgot about my existence. **Normally, the only record the company has about me is I did a 3 weeks internship** during June 2009 that I completed on the initial planned period.

Should I simply bet that he forgot about my face and my name ? Or if for that time I should put that internship on my resume along with the other internships, what I should say in my cover letter **in order to let him understand I wouldn’t be a bad fit** despite my resume telling somewhat otherwise ?

Comment: It is quite likely that the experience was much more significant for you than it was for this recruiter, so he may have long forgotten it. And in twelve years I'd hope both of you have grown up a bit (questioning you about it for two hours sounds ridiculous to me).

Comment: @gnasher729 for the questioning, it was a deadline. he was repeatedly telling me he wasn’t convinced and that I need to tell more without giving any directions. At 11H10 he finally let me out. **I’m much more concerned about what the school told in terms of work environment and what he will think of my application than what I did**.

Comment: Actually I have personal knowledge of 2 LinkedIn profiles where I know someone has left an organization years ago (as many as 8 years ago in one case) and they still have the same information listed. In 1 case, someone is still working at the same organization but they have their old, entry-level position listed. So it's quite possible the information is incorrect.

Comment: @Zorkolot I went to the company. He still works there, but they denied me to meet him or let him know I went there on the basis I was a stranger (I didn t told I worked with him).

Comment: Ok so the profile was correct. Might as well put the application in, but the only issue I see is if you're ok working there under this person and only you can answer that.

Answer (score 8):

> How to apply to a company where the technical recruiter wanted to fire me 12 years ago?

Don't worry about the recruiter.  Apply as you would for any other company.  The worst thing that can happen is that you do not get the job.

If the recruiter doesn't hire you because he is holding a grudge against you for the past 12 years, then this company is probably not worth it.

Comment: `If the recruiter doesn't hire you because he is holding a grudge against you for the past 12 years, then this company is probably not worth it.` I’m rather thinking how should I write my cover letter in that case that I changed in the way I won’t be a bad fit despite my resume telling somewhat otherwise. There are 2 weeks left for applying to most colleges, I can no longer ignore a single company.

Comment: @user2284570, How many companies are you applying to in total? You're taking so much time thinking about this one company, you could have applied to 10 other companies in the meantime. Stop wasting time. Apply to this company. And move on to the next one.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk large companies don’t want to hear about apprentice without a school and college don’t want to hear about students having failed their bachelor degree so many times without a company. It’s hard to know if a small company is delegating their ɪᴛ to a contractor or if they are doing themselves completely. And on those left many recruiters are against white‑collar apprenticeships.But for that company, that guy is regularly accepting speculative applications for peoples passing their associate degree in ɪᴛ.So yes I spend 2 or 3 hours finding a company.Which is why it is worthing it

Comment: In addition to this Linkedin InMail’s costs money. And by looking for job 18 hours a day 7 days a week for the past months, there’s nothing left on job boards.

Comment: @user2284570, In what country are you located in? "And on those left many recruiters are against white‑collar apprenticeships." Maybe you should reconsider doing your masters. In IT, you rarely need a Masters. Maybe try looking for a normal full time job (at the same time you're looking for an apprenticeship). My guess is that you'll find a full time job in IT (one that earns you way more money) long before you'll find one of those supposed apprenticeships.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I m located in France. Without a Master or engineering degree (BAC+5) I will be paid at the minimal wage for the remainning time of my life. I have my little brother to take care so I can t do that. Being a student who never stopped  studying is a legal status (the differrence between formation initiale and formation continue). Without it, tuition is approaching United Kindom levels (18 000€ per year instead of around 600€). Also you can t pretend to be an apprentice in that case but a trainnee (contrat professionnalisation).

Comment: The differrence is with an apprentice, I would pay almost no tax with my wage which means 300€ per months on the minimal monthly wage (which means I would be earning more than I would ever earn straight from the start). On the company side, it also means almost not tax to pay on the wage (around 400€ less per months on the case of minimal monthly wage) https://www.urssaf.fr/portail/home/administration-et-collectivite-t/beneficier-dune-exoneration/le-contrat-dapprentissage-dans-l/exoneration.html For the company there s also a 8000€ hiring bonus for the first year and 2000€ for the second year.

Comment: @user2284570, Ah ok. I'm actually from France, but I left France a long time ago. I'm glad I don't have to deal with that nonsense.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk in addition to this bonus, the state is reimburshing the wage in full for very small companies (less than 10 persons).So it s not only a work for free plan but hire and receive money in addition to the valuable work performed by the apprentice. It is also applicable to foreign companies without registering a subsidary which led me looking for an apprenticeship in Florida and Virigin Islands since I also want to apply to a college in Guadeloupe.Those amount of state help is telling you how heard it is to find an apprenticeship and even more for a contrat de professionnalisation

Comment: An apprentice must also be below 30 years old and I m 27 for a 2 years apprenticeship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126686/discussion-between-user2284570-and-stephan-branczyk).

Comment: Somehow, I'm reminded of a Victor Hugo plot where the authority can't see that someone has changed for the better. Les Miserables anyone? This would be totally different in a country where people are expected to fail and learn from failure. Have you learned?

Comment: Are you even sure the recruiter still works there? Bringing up the old conflict might actually reduce your chances.

Comment: @DavidR : surtout que je suis en France.

Comment: @Llewellyn definitely. I tried to meet him and they told me he wasn’t here that day.